# Ist every axiom of ZFC Independent of the Rest?

Tags: set-theory

I've read that AC has this property, but I have not found if the rest also have it.

Comment: So, the answer seems to be no, but why the downvote? The fact that if I ask 'is X true' and the answer is no, its not, and someone downvotes seemingly because of that is not of my understanding. That is the point of asking, to be refuted or confirmed.

Comment: Downvotes likely due to lack of effort. This problem is bound to be thoroughly dissected, already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ZFC is phrased, there are infinitely many redundancies in the axioms.

For example, the following are two instances of the axiom scheme of specification:

$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff z \in x \land z = z))$$

$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff z \in x \land (z = z \land z = z))$$

These are two different axioms which are logically equivalent to each other, so neither is independent of the other.

Furthermore, depending on the phrasing of the axiom scheme of replacement, the entire axiom scheme of specification is not necessary as every instance follows from the scheme of replacement.